# SQL Server 2016 Query High CPU Usage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a Microsoft query that kicks off whenever I start a new SSMS session and execute the first query of the session. I have performed a trace on it while it was executing and determined that it was incrementing the value of one of the parameters. Is there a way to disable this from executing?

```
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JOHNP'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JOHNP#'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JOHNT'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JOHNT#'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JONG'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JONG#'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JONL'
@_msparam_0=N'CO',@_msparam_1=N'JONL#'
```

```
SELECT
u.name AS [Name],
u.principal_id AS [ID],
CAST(CASE WHEN u.principal_id < 5 OR u.principal_id = 16382 OR u.principal_id = 16383 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
CASE WHEN N''U'' = u.type THEN 0 WHEN N''G'' = u.type THEN 1 WHEN N''S'' = u.type THEN 2 WHEN N''C'' = u.type THEN 3 WHEN N''K'' = u.type THEN 4 WHEN N''E'' = u.type THEN 5 WHEN N''X'' = u.type THEN 6 END AS [LoginType],
CAST(CASE dp.state WHEN N''G'' THEN 1 WHEN ''W'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [HasDBAccess],
u.sid AS [Sid],
u.create_date AS [CreateDate],
u.modify_date AS [DateLastModified],
ISNULL(u.default_schema_name,N'''') AS [DefaultSchema],
ISNULL(ak.name,N'''') AS [AsymmetricKey],
ISNULL(cert.name,N'''') AS [Certificate],
ISNULL(suser_sname(u.sid),N'''') AS [Login],
ISNULL(u.default_language_lcid, -1) AS [DefaultLanguageLcid],
ISNULL(u.default_language_name,N'''') AS [DefaultLanguageName],
u.authentication_type AS [AuthenticationType],

        CASE
        WHEN N''C'' = u.type THEN 1
        WHEN N''K'' = u.type THEN 2        
        WHEN N''S'' = u.type AND SUSER_SNAME(u.sid) is null AND u.authentication_type != 2 THEN 3
        ELSE 0 END
       AS [UserType]
FROM
sys.database_principals AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS dp ON dp.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id and dp.type = @_msparam_0
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.asymmetric_keys AS ak ON ak.sid = u.sid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.certificates AS cert ON cert.sid = u.sid
WHERE
(u.type in (''U'', ''S'', ''G'', ''C'', ''K'' ,''E'', ''X''))and(u.name=@_msparam_1)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)
```

This has been determined to be an issue with Intellisense. When Intellisense is disabled this is no longer an issue. I am now trying to figure out how to fix this so that I can continue to use Intellisense.

#### Details:

- With Intellisense: 687 CPU seconds, 12,394 reads, and a duration of 811.
- Without Intellisense: 16 CPU seconds, 1,160 reads, and a duration of 123.

#### SSMS Version: 13.0.16106.4

[Further examination of a trace revealed Intellisense as the culprit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVZzU.png)

Comment: How many sql server logins do you have in total? What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: @gofr1 I have determined this to be an issue with Intellisense. I've edited the original post to include these updated details.

Comment: SSMS and Azure Data Studio both have this problem. I am just curios how many logins do you have in your db? This problem usually occurs with huge amount of SQL Server Logins.